# Sonar not respecting //NOSONAR for duplication

Tags: sonarqube, code-duplication

When a line of code is decorated with a `//NOSONAR` comment, Sonar seems to correctly ignore specific code quality rules (eg non conforming naming standards).

However, code duplication problems are still detected for lines so decorated.

Is there a simple way to make Sonar ignore duplication?

Note: I don't want to create a special exception on the sonar server, because every dev had their own local sonar instance, so it has to work "everywhere".

Answer (score 1):

//NOSONAR only work on issues. But the root cause of your issue is "every dev had their own local sonar instance". This goes against the SonarQube philosophy and prevent you from settings exclusions. The question then would be: Why don't you have a single central SonarQube server?

Comment: I didn't say there isn't a central sonar server - of course there is one. Every dev has their own instance so they can test changes to code locally before pushing to the build server, which lets the main sonar data history only contain results from builds (doesn't pollute the history with non-build micro change "tests")

Comment: My point is that each developer having their own SonarQube server is against the SonarQube philosophy. They can check their code locally without having any local SonarQube server and without pushing any data to the central SonarQube server. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code#AnalyzingSourceCode-IncrementalMode